# fire causesValidation before onClientClick for button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have this button to add info into a database. I have a few `RequiredFieldValidator` to inform the user when they haven't supplied all the necessary data. When this button is clicked it validates the data but regardless of whether it is filled or empty it gets added anyway. I tried to fix this by having a check for no input in the javascript function `checkPage()` but if it returns `false` my validation error message never appears. If it returns `true` then the blank item gets inserted into the database. How can I only run `OnClick` if it passes the validation?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text=" Add " Width="75px" OnClientClick="return checkPage()"
                        OnClick="AdminButtonAdd_Click" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="adminGroup"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your AdminButtonAdd_Click method?

Comment: It just takes all the values from each of the input textboxes and inserts into the database. The textboxes each have their own `RequiredFieldValidator `

Comment: did you enclose the Get values in if (IsValid) {...
} block?

Comment: does Page.IsValid check all validation?

Comment: I'm not too clear on the function. If I did `if (Page.IsValid)` does that go in if everything is valid or after the validators have run

Comment: Page.IsValid checks if your form entry is valid and then runs the next steps.